# Branding an Eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, branding

I have a RCP app which I want to "brand", i.e. create a proper text for the about box with build id. Simple stuff. Unfortunately this wasn't as easy as I had hoped, and now I am stuck.

My RCP project is launched from a project configuration and is not deployed as plugins through features.

I have tried entering stuff directly in the product configuration -> branding tab, but when I do, the input isn't formatted, meaning I have no newlines and no possibility to externalize strings like I want to. I have also tried creating about.ini, about.properties and about.mappings in an attempt to use the %< property >, but still no luck. The about box is a standard org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction.

Every tutorial on the net says different things, so now I feel pretty confused. I have also tried to replicate what is done with branding in the Eclipse repos, without any luck.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. product configuration branding will honor newlines and externalized strings (defined in plugin.properties); 2. did you remember to add about.ini to build.properties? btw, about.ini is used for customizing what you see if you click on a feature button in "About eclipse".

Comment: This clears things up a bit. However I still cant get Eclipse to resolve strings from plugin.properties. I have "blurb=test" in plugin.properties, and try to resolve this by setting the aboutText property in plugin.xml to %blurb. When opening the about box I only get %blurb. Do I have to do anything to externalize that string in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is needed is this line in the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Bundle-Localization: plugin
```

guido's comment on my question sheds some light on what the different files are for as well.